# Nautilus: "Cannot load supported server method list. Please check your gvfs installation"

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gvfs, sftp

I was trying to connect to a `sftp` server using Nautilus... but I could not as it showed this error:

[image: Nautilus Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know what the problem could be, but the `sftp` support for `gvfs` is provided by the `gvfs-backends` packages, so I'd try to reinstall the package and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-backends
```

Comment: "Do this" without explanation is never a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

[gksudo Nautilus only : "Cannot load supported server method list. Please check your gvfs installation"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278127/gksudo-nautilus-only-cannot-load-supported-server-method-list-please-check-y)

This did the trick for me (I use Linux Mint): 
dbus-launch nemo &

Comment: Don't share only the link. link can be shared as comment or as duplicate flag (which you are not allowed to use yet) If you answer, provide the essential part of solution and share the link for reference and more detail