# gksudo Nautilus only : "Cannot load supported server method list. Please check your gvfs installation"

Tags: nautilus

Here a screenshot (in danish, the english equiv can be seen here https://askubuntu.com/a/187657/107445, similar question but the answers does not solve the problem)

[image]

The very weird thing is, that this error *only* appears when I try to connect to a server from a nautilus opened as system user / gksudo. From a Nautilus opened as "anonymous" user there is no problems connecting to server. I am also able to connect to server from "places".

I have runned

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```

and as suggested in this similar question https://askubuntu.com/a/187657/107445

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-backends
```

also

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but still, this error appears, and only appears in Nautilus as system user. Does someone know the answer to this? I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when trying to run Nautilus outside a desktop session - I'd just connected in with "ssh -X ..." from another host and typed "nautilus &".

If I run:

```
dbus-launch nautilus &
```

Then the error goes away and it all works.  This makes sense as GVFS needs a DBUS session context, so I'm happy this is expected behaviour on my system.  If I was seeing this same error when running Nautilus on a regular desktop login then I'd suspect a configuration problem, but it would still be worth looking at DBUS as a culprit.

Maybe the developers could make that message more helpful!

Comment: When I do this, I get Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Worth noting that this allows WSL2 to connect to gvfs via X11 browser windows on the local system.